# Soft-deleteable, Disable for entity

Tags: symfony, filter

I'm using DoctrineExtensions with StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle to get the soft-deleteable behaviour.

It works really well but I need to turn it off for one of my entities. How I can do that ? I can see that there is method 'disableForEntity', maybe i should set somewhere configuration with this method which would work everywhere ?
I want to turn off this filter for one entity on the application (all actions).

Problem is because my specific Entity extends Base Entity with this filter.

Is this possible or I have to disable it every time I want to use my one specific entity ?

Answer (score 0):

i think in you entity you have:

```
<?php

 namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

 /**
  * ...
  * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
  * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Foo
 {
    /**
     * @var \DateTime $deletedAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;
```

you have to remove the behaviour from the entity that should withoud soft delete SO you have only to remove

```
* @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
```

Comment: I have it in my Base Entity. And my specific Entity extends this Base Entity... Like this "class AdmUserHasMails  extends BaseEntity".

Comment: You can't disable the behavior for one entity because it's just your implementation who makes all your entities softdeletable not the doctrine extension.

Comment: Make a SoftDeleteableEntity that extends BaseEntity, the former having the annotation and the latter not. Then extend your model classes from the appropriate super class. Of course this becomes a headache if you have several custom classes like this, at which point you should instead consider moving the annotations to the real entity classes. In short: Don't put things in a superclass that doesn't apply to *all* subclasses.